# Google Apps Script: Using Var in a Formula?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to create a Google script for a Sheet so that end users can import a list of email addresses from a sheet on another spreadsheet. Each user has their own sheet on this spreadsheet, and it is named after their own address. So, user1 has a sheet user1@example.com on this spreadsheet, and user two has their own sheet, and so on.

I can use Session.getActiveUser().getEmail() to give me their email address, but I  can't find a way to use that as a variable within IMPORTRANGE.

Is it possible to do this? If not, is it possible to achieve the same result through another method, like pointing at the sheet using the email var and storing the addresses in an array, which is then written to the target sheet?

Here's the relevant snippet of the script for reference. Note that I replaced the URL for the google sheet with sheetlink, and the bit that says ""useremail!A1:A100"" is where I was hoping to use the useremail var to fill it with the result of getEmail().

```
function importlist() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheetname = 'Blacklist';
var useremail = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();

if (ss.getSheetByName(sheetname) == null) {
    ss.insertSheet(sheetname);
    ss.getSheetByName(sheetname).getRange("A1").setFormula('=IMPORTRANGE("sheetlink","useremail!A1:A100")');
} else {
    ss.getSheetByName(sheetname).getRange("A1").setFormula('=IMPORTRANGE("sheetlink","useremail!A1:A100")');
    ss.getSheetByName(sheetname).activate()
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't directly use the name of the variable in the string. It'll be treated as that word literally. You have a combine strings with a variable like this:

```
IMPORTRANGE("sheetlink", useremail + "!A1:A100")
```

Comment: Unfortunately I get a similar error when I use your version, it still treats useremail as that word literally rather than a variable. 


It gives me:

=IMPORTRANGE("docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1e9....", useremail + "!A1:A100")

I tried replacing the + with an & as well but it then treated useremail like a defined range and didn't fill it even when I defined it with the target email address.

Comment: Just played around with it some more, if I do an & instead of a + and write a defined range with the useremail string in it to the sheet before I call importrange, it works great. Thanks for getting me there!